# weasyprint doesn't apply css style in output file

Tags: python, weasyprint

I'm trying to output a `pdf` from an `html` page using a `python` script with `weasyprint` library. I got the output as a `pdf` file, but the `pdf` page is not styled however I'm using bootstrap css style. This is a snippet of my code:

```
HTML('./result.html').write_pdf('./result.pdf', stylesheets=[CSS(filename='./bootstrap.css')])
```

result.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class='text-primary'>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

WeasyPrint version: 0.40

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your routes are correct, you have to remove the 'filename=' in the CSS like:

```
html = HTML('./result.html') #html file location
html.write_pdf(target='./result.pdf', stylesheets=[CSS('bootstrap.css')])
```